# What is better way to create reference within 2 SQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have Corporate table which collect Organizations. 
Each organization could has several branches. 
If there are many branches it is also the main one - head office.

How is better to make it?

1. add in Corporate table primary branch foreign key?
2. or add in Branches table is_primary column to mark it as true.

I suppose a second way could be a preferable but I need than some algorithm to be sure that there are no 2 head_offices for corporate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make three tables:

1. One is Corporate which has org_id as primary key.
2. Another is Branch which has branch_id as primary key.
3. Third is CorporateBranch table, which has org_id, branch_id as primary key

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your support. That's all that I have needed.

Comment: I think you would also have to add a unique index on org_id (CorporateBranch) to ensure a Corporate only has 1 main branch (unless you can have multiple main branches)